# Disabling shader on rviz::marker

Tags: rviz

Is there a way to disable shading using rviz::Markerbase ?

I use the exact same color for arrow and wireframe, but the shading of the arrow make it darker in rviz :
[image: Bounding Box with Orientation Arrow]

Thanks by advance !